# Vue keep line chart updated using props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

Vue 2.x

chart-js: 2.x

vue-chartjs: 3.x

I am sending data from a websocket from my parent component to my child component where I plan to generate a line chart (think of constantly updating line chart).

Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <ChartComponent :aqiLineChartData="aqiLineChartData"/>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
.
data: function () {
        return {
            aqiLineChartData: {}
        };
},
created: function () {
  //call the websocket and get the data
  this.aqiLineChartData.lastUpdatedTime = moment(Date.now()).format("h:mm a");
  this.aqiLineChartData.data = //websocket data (which is a number)
}
</script>
```

ChartComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-card elevation="2">
      <v-card-title>Live AQI Comparison</v-card-title>
      <line-chart 
        :chartData="datacollection"
      ></line-chart>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import LineChart from "./LineChart.js";

export default {
  name: "AQIChartComponent",
  props: ['aqiLineChartData'],
  components: {
    LineChart
  },
  data() {
    return {
      datacollection: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [],
      },
      trend: {
        data: [],
        label: "Trend",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false,
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        tooltips: {
          titleFontSize: 20,
          bodyFontSize: 25,
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
  },
  created() {
    //console.log(this.aqiLineChartData);
    this.datacollection.labels.push(this.aqiLineChartData.lastUpdatedTime);

    this.trend.data.push(this.aqiLineChartData.data);
    this.datacollection.datasets.push(this.trend);
  },
  watch: {
    aqiLineChartData: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('Prop changed: ', newValue, ' | was: ', oldValue)
        this.datacollection.labels.push(newValue.lastUpdatedTime);

        this.trend.data.push(newValue.data);
        this.datacollection.datasets.push(this.trend);
      }
      
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

LineChart.js

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['chartData', 'options'],
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  },
  watch: {
    chartData() {
      this.$data._chart.update();
    }
  }
}
```

I have trimmed some information for readability.

In ChartComponent.vue I am watching the aqiLineChartData to detect any new change and push the data and time values into the respective arrays inside the datacollection.

In LineChart.js I am watching the chartData but the line chart does not seem to be updating.

I am trying to formulate a solution on how I can send websocket data to the child component and keep the line chart updated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're updating subproperties of each of the watched objects, but Vue 2 watchers don't monitor subproperty changes by default.

One solution is to use the [`deep` flag](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) for the watchers:

```js
// ChartComponent.vue
export default {
  watch: {
    aqiLineChartData: {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
      handler() {/*...*/}
    }
  }
}

// LineChart.js
export default {
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {/*...*/},
    }
  }
}
```